# cannot implicitly convert type db.entities1 to system.collection.generic.list<aspnetWEBAPI.Home_Visits_Request> when post WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created the post action in WEB-API project and this is the steps :

1- connect to database and updated Model from the database and using Data.Edmx

2- Created the Model homeVisit

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using aspnetWEBAPI;

    public class homeVisit
    {
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<Home_Visits_Request> Data { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

3- Created the controller and post action

```
[HttpPost]
        [ActionName("posthomevisitrequest")]
        public HttpResponseMessage posthomevisitrequest([FromBody] Home_Visits_Request Labrequest)
        {

            using (DBEntities1 entities = new DBEntities1())
            {

                 entities.Home_Visits_Request.Add(Labrequest);
                 entities.SaveChanges();

                homeVisit homeRequest = new homeVisit
                {
                    Success = true,
                    Data = entities,
                    Message = "Data Inserted "
                };

                FalseStatus falsestat = new FalseStatus
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "Cannot Insert Data "
                };

                if (!entities.Home_Visits_Request.Any())
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, falsestat);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, homeRequest);
                }

                
            }
```

the error shows in step 3 in this line  `Data = entities,`

```
"cannot implicitly convert type db.entities1 to system.collection.generic.list<aspnetWEBAPI.Home_Visits_Request>
```

and another error in this line  if (!entities.Any())

```
"DBEntities1 does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method Any accepting the first argument for DBEntities1 could be found are you missing a using directive or assembly reference ? "
```

I used same code and structure with Get Method but I think there is some changes I need to change with post method , How to solve this error your help please .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code:

```
 using (DBEntities1 entities = new DBEntities1())
            {

                 entities.Set<Home_Visits_Request>().Add(Labrequest);
            var result=   entities.SaveChanges();

                
          if (result == 0)
                {
            FalseStatus falsestat = new FalseStatus
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "Cannot Insert Data "
                };

              return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, 
 falsestat);
                }
              
                 homeVisit homeRequest = new homeVisit
                {
                    Success = true,
                    Data = entities.Set<Home_Visits_Request>().ToList(),
                    Message = "Data Inserted "
                };

                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
 homeRequest);
```

and check that you have using System.Linq; in your controller class.

Update:

If you want to return only the added record, change your model class

```
public class homeVisit
    {
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public Home_Visits_Request Data { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and use this code:

```
 homeVisit homeRequest = new homeVisit
                {
                    Success = true,
                    Data = Labrequest,
                    Message = "Data Inserted "
                };
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
 homeRequest);
```

I think it is a good idea to wrap save in a try...catch block too

Comment: Thank you so much its working without errors , but i need one more thing now the data after inserted its return all the rows in the table can I return only the row inserted  Data = entities.Set<Home_Visits_Request>().ToList(),

Comment: I updated the code and using new var result   @ZiadAdnan

Comment: thank you sir for your help I'm happy with this solution :) :)